# How to introduce a lint in bitbucket pipeline in an old repository?

Tags: php, docker, bitbucket, phpcs

I have some repositories where I want to install a lint. My main concern here is that it's a lot of old code that would certainly not pass, and fixing everything is simply not a viable options. So I only want to use the lint on new code.

And I found a tool that seem to be the right choice, [phpcs changed](https://github.com/sirbrillig/phpcs-changed)

What it does is basically to run `phpcs` (codesniffer) on the git diff of the files instead of the files directly.

It works perfectly locally with a command like

```
docker compose run --rm test ./vendor/bin/phpcs-changed --git --git-base develop src
```

But I'm having some troubles running them in a bitbucket pipeline. When I put the above command in a pipeline, I get the error that the current directory is not a git repository. When I use `phpcs` instead of `phpcs-changed` it does work, which makes sense.

I feel a bit lost how to proceed here. If `phpcs-changed` is not the right tool, I'm completely open for other options. What I want to do is simply to make the lint only act on new code.

Comment: You need to share more details about your pipeline and the actual error message given.